# pjscrape and openStreetMap - how to trigger "More Results" button?

Tags: jquery, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm using pjscrape to scrape latitude data from:

http://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=rossmann#map=19/50.53776/8.72757

and "my_config.js" code is:

```
pjs.addSuite({
  url: 'http://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=rossmann#map=19/50.53776/8.72757',
  nextPage: function () {
        var next = $('.search_more');
        if (next.length) {
            next.click();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },
  scraper: function() {
    var result = []
    var links = $('a')
    lat = links.map(function(index, elem) { 
        return $(elem).attr("data-max-lat")
    }).toArray()

    result = result.concat(lat)
    return result
  }
});
```

I'm getting only first 10 results. How to trigger "More Results" button on the web page?

I saw similar example: [How to go to the next page for scraping in PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979753/how-to-go-to-the-next-page-for-scraping-in-phantomjs). I followed the logic, but it seams my "NextPage" function still not working. Also, I'm not familiar with jquery, but most of the code does what I want, so I'd like to fix the "nextPage" function in jquery.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a basic `<a>` link in openStreetMap "More results" code than you can feed to pjscraper:
`<a class="button load_more" href="/geocoder/...">More results</a>`

According to [docs](https://github.com/nrabinowitz/pjscrape/blob/master/tests/test_recursive_selector.js) you have to use `moreUrls` option to supply selector to the next page.

Also there is an option to limit your search to a given number of pages with `maxDepth` option (if you don't I suspect the scrape will run forever and results are only returned upon run completion).

And just to be on the safe side I suppose using `noconflict` option as well. If it is on, jQuery will be declared on the scraped page as `_pjs.$`, not as `$`, so that it will not interfere with page's scripts if some other script uses `$` variable.

So, this config works:

```
pjs.addSuite({
  url: 'http://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=rossmann#map=19/50.53776/8.72757',
  noConflict: true,
  moreUrls : '.load_more',
  scraper: function() {
    var result = []
    var links = _pjs.$('a')
    lat = links.map(function(index, elem) { 
        return _pjs.$(elem).attr("data-max-lat")
    }).toArray()

    result = result.concat(lat)
    return result
  },
   maxDepth: 5
});
```

End of console output:

```
* Writing 60 items
* Suite 0-sub0-sub0-sub0-sub0-sub0 complete
["50.537813","51.7504874","51.8143035","53.4737368","52.4913574","51.1978692","53.5920406","53.4900032","53.49275","51.5024151","52.1984359","52.13419
19","53.8636212","51.5384084","51.5371952","48.1181396","52.151562","52.4346399","48.0577744","52.6403921","52.2545572","52.2504471","50.0440849","48.
3681909","49.6808955","52.6338293","53.6031792","51.3843645","49.824228","52.2096506","47.5663295","54.1074032","50.1156358","53.3241788","54.6345055"
,"52.322425","50.8221216","50.1329512","48.2611337","49.8259861","52.2488409","52.4392467","53.0738941","50.1053255","50.1015457","50.1041568","50.680
7764","53.5991453","51.6823706","53.4000913","51.2493895","51.0344969","53.0784862","54.7855778","51.6745303","52.8624927","47.951209","48.304389","49
.9745581","52.1767346"]
* Saved 60 items
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For most of the things I haven't even had an idea that exist and I checked all the examples. Your explanation will be valuable to many of those who'd like to work with pjscrape. Thank you once again.